# Вызов сервлета по URL

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Есть некий `header` со ссылками на `jsp`. Одна из jsp отображает результат выборки из БД. При это саму выборку делает `servlet` и потом отправляет клиенту jsp с результатом выборки. Т.е. кликая по ссылке в header-e первом делом стартует `servlet`. Т.е. `url` содержит адрес именно сервлета. Но вот проблема, ведь `servlet` я запросил не через `<form>`+`submit`, а значит методы `doGet/doPost` не вызываются и нет `request/response` объектов. Как мне начать работу в таком сервлете, какой метод использовать?

`doGet` "автоматом" у меня почему-то не запускается. ниже пример. По ссылке **goto** переходим на сервлет ns.java но он не печатает текст, а значит `doGet` не вызывается. При тех же условиях но через форму и кнопку всё работает.

JSP

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>


    <body>
        <a href="/mS/ns.java">goto</a>
        <br>
        <form name="frm" action="act">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="goto" name="btn" />  
        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```

Сервлет:

```
public class ns extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println("ttttt");
        System.out.println("n-----------------------------------------s");
    }

}
```

[image: Структура проекта]

Answer (score 3):

он будет вызывать метод `doGet()`, если
в `web.xml` прописали следующее:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.servlet.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

то он должен найти, и он у вас будет доступен по ссылке `/MyServlet`

Comment: у меня не получается почему-то. дополнил вопрос простым примером. это какой-то баг? прошу помощи...

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка тут:

```
<a href="/mS/ns.java">goto</a>
```

`href` должно быть равным тому, что у вас между тегами  `<url-pattern>...</url-pattern>` в `web.xml` при маппинге целевого сервлета.